# How to make a copy of a table before delete ( django pre_delete )

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django so I guess my Question is basic but I need your help.
I have a table called Answer.

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    id      = models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True)
    sku     = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=secrets.token_urlsafe(16), editable=False)
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null= True)
    topic   = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

it's for a forum.

Before a user deletes his/her answer, I want to make a copy of the answer. I want to make a new table that has the values of this table, for example, a table named DeletedAnswer that has all the values in Answer table.

thanks

**Update :**

I did it with pre_delete, here is what I did :

created a new model named DeleteAnswer:

```
class DeleteAnswer(models.Model):
    id          = models.AutoField(auto_created=True,primary_key=True)
    sku         = models.CharField(max_length=128, default=secrets.token_urlsafe(16), editable=False)    
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    topic       = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)    
    content     = models.TextField()
    delete_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created     = models.DateTimeField()
```

and then I did it with signals and pre_delete :

```
@receiver(pre_delete,sender=Answer)
def delete_answer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    d  = DeleteAnswer()
    d.sku = instance.sku
    d.content = instance.content
    d.topic = instance.topic
    d.user = instance.user
    d.created = instance.created
    d.delete_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    d.save()
```

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using [`django-simple-history`](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.2/querying_history.html).

Comment: Note that the `pre_delete` might not be sufficient, since deletes in "bulk" bypass the `pre_delete` signal.

Comment: You can just add a boolean field called `deleted` and set it to `True`. And in your query just exclude the deleted ones. Much simpler than creating a whole new table and create a copy. But still, it depends on your requirements.